# How to store hashes for many datablocks, and retrieve lists by the hash?

Tags: .net, performance, algorithm, low-level

I'm working on an opensource project implementing deduplication. (For a link to the project, see the two hyperlinks below)
Performance of the project currently is quite okay, but degrades as more blocks get written to disk.
This is due to the HashManager. For each block written, the hashmanager stores a Hash-BlockId pair. For the deduplication process, a list of block identifiers is needed which have a given hash. (hash used is Crc32)
For the interface of the HashManager, see [the source](https://github.com/terwoord/overdrive/blob/master/Sources/Core/IHashManager.cs).

The current [implementation](https://github.com/terwoord/overdrive/blob/master/Sources/Core/Implementations/SimpleHashManager.cs) of the interface stores the lists in 256 files (crc & 0xFF), and loads a complete list into memory. When another list is needed, the previous list is saved and the next one is loaded. Besides the fact that this could cause memory exhaustion, this means degrading performance.

What good options are there to overcome the issue?

(Just to clearify: blocks are checked completely to see if they match before deduplicating)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert at on-disk structures, but I have heard that a B-Tree is often used for implementing key-value maps which are stored on disk. So I guess you could have a B-Tree index of CRCs, which then have some sort of link stored to a list of block ids. You might also be able to combine the list into the B-Tree structure, by effectively having a key which is the concatenation of the CRC and then the block ID, and do what is then effectively a prefix/range query on the B-Tree.

[Wikipedia Page on B-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree): "In computer science, a B-tree is a tree data structure that keeps data sorted and allows searches, sequential access, insertions, and deletions in logarithmic time. The B-tree is a generalization of a binary search tree in that a node can have more than two children. (Comer 1979, p. 123) Unlike self-balancing binary search trees, the B-tree is optimized for systems that read and write large blocks of data. It is commonly used in databases and filesystems."

Comment: I came across B-trees in my search, but it seems to me like a complex algorithm. Are you familiar with any good implementations?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 256 list files to store crcs, the first obvious step is to put all the crcs that start with a byte of zero in list 0, all the ones with a byte of 1 in list file 1, etc. then store only the last three bytes of the crc in each file. this will save 25% of your key storage, and perhaps speed up processing also.

the second thing to do is make a 4 gigaBIT in-memory flag array, to show if a 4 byte crc has been registered in the lists. this will vastly speed up adding new items to the array, because you will know if you need to look up an existing entry first - if the bit is zero, that crc has not been used yet.

According to a paper by the developers of data domain, this unneeded look up is what slows down the ingest process the most (they have a different method of avoiding it).

I assume you are saving the list because you are modifying them. I would suggest that instead of rewriting the whole list, you put all changes at the end of the file, so you can append to the end of the file instead of rewriting the entire list. Used a linked list structure that begins with pointers at the tail end of the file, writing a new header to the list at the end of the file with each append. You can mark an entry for deletion by writing a new entry higher up the list with a delete flag on. Then periodically you can garbage collect each list to reduce the list size (batch process once a week or month, for example). You can do the same with list modifications. Just write a new entry to replace the old entry, with a flag perhaps. Then garbage collect periodically to remove the older entry.

Anything you can do to structure the lists so you do not need to load the entire thing in memory each time will speed things up. Move as little data as you can, as seldom as you can.

This is the first thing I have written on Stack Overflow, so please excuse if my posting doesn't follow the preferred norms.

I note by the instructions above my reply edit area that I am not supposed to ask for clarification, I guess that is so I can have more fun just guessing what the exact problem is. I hope my guess is close and my answer contains useful elements.